# Lightning Carousel component is repeating indicators if we have less than 3 images

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I am creating dynamic lightning carousel, so when I have less than 3 images it is repeating the indicators. 
Example: Lets say if I have images img1 and img2, then in the carousel I am seeing it as im1,img2,img1,img2,img1. 
But I want to display only 2 images (img1 and img2), it shouldn't repeat same images again.

**Here is the code:**

```
<lightning:carousel disableAutoScroll="false">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.recordList}" var="l">
                        <lightning:carouselImage src = "{!l.image__c}" 
                        header = "{!l.Header}" description = "{!l.Description}" 
                        alternativeText = "{!l.AlterText}" href = "{!l.imgUrl}">
                        </lightning:carouselImage>
                    </aura:iteration>
                  </lightning:carousel>
```

In the above code "recordList" contains records from custom object.

Can anyone please let me know how can i stop the repetition of images. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show how you are getting data in `recordList`? and also give the data in `recordList`? (this is not reproducible and so asking)

Comment: @Test User, first of all is your rendering carousel. I am getting `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot set property 'tabIndex' of undefined]
Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:carousel}` error with the same code.